# How to optimise my spark script in Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

In my script, I have a table with 3 columns, which are `vehicleId`, `tripStartDateTime`  and `correlationId`.
The table can be partitioned by `vehicleId` column.

```
+------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------+
|vehicleId         |tripStartDateTime   |correlationId                       |
+------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------+
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|2023-07-26T16:35:34Z|1f036bb8-cac4-43c1-b29e-a7646884fe2e|
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|2023-07-26T17:27:38Z|134b785e-e013-41b1-aabc-094a90b95482|
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|2023-07-26T18:04:16Z|51fb0e53-2938-431c-8825-7f461849dfe3|
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|2023-07-26T18:32:46Z|954a4f96-2c51-403b-9fd5-d07a7cdc35dd|
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|2023-07-26T18:40:18Z|811a1336-27f3-4e8c-99cc-22f5debe21a3|
|8eba-55a058fb4dd0f|2023-07-20T10:35:34Z|1f036bff-cac4-dddd-ddsa-a7646884fe2e|
|8eba-55a058fb4dd0f|2023-07-20T10:65:34Z|23226bff-cac4-dddd-ddsa-a7646884fe2e|
...
```

Inside each `vehicleId`(partition), I want to process rows one by one based on `tripStartDateTime`. Each row will be passed to a UDF function, and in the UDF, there are complex calculations and the result of each row will be saved into another table. The next row will use the results generated by the previous rows. So each row must be processed in sequence.

**How to write an efficient script to make sure each partition can be processed concurrently(because one vehicle doesn't affect other vehicles), but inside a partition, records will be processed one by one in order?**

My current solution is to prepare a UDF, pass each row to the UDF and call UDF in a for loop. But this is slow though I use a multi-node cluster in Databricks.

```
for (row <- df.collect()) {
   processRowUDF(row)
}
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions about how to optimise it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom defined pandas udf of type `PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG`. It takes in grouped data (in this case grouped per vehicleId) and returns list of lists which can be exploded to insert to another table or create another dataframe. Following is an example of it.

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from typing import Iterator, Tuple
import pandas as pd


sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [

["00045b1b-0ac9-4dce", "2023-07-26T16:35:34Z", "1f036bb8-cac4-43c1-b29e-a7646884fe2e"],
["00045b1b-0ac9-4dce", "2023-07-26T17:27:38Z", "134b785e-e013-41b1-aabc-094a90b95482"],
["00045b1b-0ac9-4dce", "2023-07-26T18:04:16Z", "51fb0e53-2938-431c-8825-7f461849dfe3"],
["00045b1b-0ac9-4dce", "2023-07-26T18:32:46Z", "954a4f96-2c51-403b-9fd5-d07a7cdc35dd"],
["00045b1b-0ac9-4dce", "2023-07-26T18:40:18Z", "811a1336-27f3-4e8c-99cc-22f5debe21a3"],
["8eba-55a058fb4dd0f", "2023-07-20T10:35:34Z", "1f036bff-cac4-dddd-ddsa-a7646884fe2e"],
["8eba-55a058fb4dd0f", "2023-07-20T10:55:34Z", "23226bff-cac4-dddd-ddsa-a7646884fe2e"],

]
columns1 =["vehicleId", "tripStartDateTime", "correlationId"]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns1)
df1 = df1.withColumn("tripStartDateTime", F.to_timestamp(F.col("tripStartDateTime")))
print("Given dataframe")
df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)

print("schema here")
print(df1.schema)



@pandas_udf(ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())), PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def custom_sum_udf(col1_series: pd.Series, col2_series: pd.Series, col3_series: pd.Series) -> ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())):
    concat_df = pd.concat([col1_series, col2_series, col3_series], axis=1)
    concat_df.columns = columns1 # declared before
    print("Process the vehicle Id")  # Do complex processing since concat_df is now a pandas dataframe.
    print(concat_df)

    max_column = concat_df["tripStartDateTime"].max()
    min_column = concat_df["tripStartDateTime"].min()

    print("max_column", max_column)
    print("min_column", min_column)
    all_result = [ [concat_df.iloc[0,0]], [str(max_column)], [str(min_column)]]

    return all_result

df_new = df1.groupby(F.col("vehicleId")).agg(custom_sum_udf(F.col("vehicleId"), F.col("tripStartDateTime"), F.col("correlationId")).alias("reduced_columns")).cache()
print("Printing the column sum, max, min")
df_new.show(n=100, truncate=False)

df_new_sep = df_new.withColumn("id_recieved", F.col("reduced_columns").getItem(0))
df_new_sep = df_new_sep.withColumn("max_over_timestamp", F.col("reduced_columns").getItem(1))
df_new_sep = df_new_sep.withColumn("min_over_timestamp", F.col("reduced_columns").getItem(2)).drop(F.col("reduced_columns"))
print("Printing the column max, min")
df_new_sep.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Given dataframe
+------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+
|vehicleId         |tripStartDateTime  |correlationId                       |
+------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|2023-07-26 22:05:34|1f036bb8-cac4-43c1-b29e-a7646884fe2e|
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|2023-07-26 22:57:38|134b785e-e013-41b1-aabc-094a90b95482|
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|2023-07-26 23:34:16|51fb0e53-2938-431c-8825-7f461849dfe3|
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|2023-07-27 00:02:46|954a4f96-2c51-403b-9fd5-d07a7cdc35dd|
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|2023-07-27 00:10:18|811a1336-27f3-4e8c-99cc-22f5debe21a3|
|8eba-55a058fb4dd0f|2023-07-20 16:05:34|1f036bff-cac4-dddd-ddsa-a7646884fe2e|
|8eba-55a058fb4dd0f|2023-07-20 16:25:34|23226bff-cac4-dddd-ddsa-a7646884fe2e|
+------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+

schema here
StructType([StructField('vehicleId', StringType(), True), StructField('tripStartDateTime', TimestampType(), True), StructField('correlationId', StringType(), True)])
    
    
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|vehicleId         |reduced_columns                                                     |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|[[00045b1b-0ac9-4dce], [2023-07-27 00:10:18], [2023-07-26 22:05:34]]|
|8eba-55a058fb4dd0f|[[8eba-55a058fb4dd0f], [2023-07-20 16:25:34], [2023-07-20 16:05:34]]|
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+

Printing the column max, min
+------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|vehicleId         |id_recieved         |max_over_timestamp   |min_over_timestamp   |
+------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|00045b1b-0ac9-4dce|[00045b1b-0ac9-4dce]|[2023-07-27 00:10:18]|[2023-07-26 22:05:34]|
|8eba-55a058fb4dd0f|[8eba-55a058fb4dd0f]|[2023-07-20 16:25:34]|[2023-07-20 16:05:34]|
+------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach using scala spark and Dataset.
There are guides available on how to write custom user defined aggregate function.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{abs, col, lit}

import scala.collection.mutable.{ArrayBuffer, ListBuffer}
import scala.math.{log => mathLog}

object VehicleDemo {

  case class VehicleInfo(
                                    vehicleId: String = null,
                                    tripStartDateTime: String = null,
                                    correlationId: String = null
                                  )


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={

    val sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")


    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Vehicle Demo")
      .config(sparkConfig)
      .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    val conf: SparkConf = spark.sparkContext.getConf

    import spark.implicits._

    val vehicleInfoList = ArrayBuffer[VehicleInfo]()
    vehicleInfoList.append(VehicleInfo("00045b1b-0ac9-4dce", "2023-07-26T16:35:34Z", "1f036bb8-cac4-43c1-b29e-a7646884fe2e"))
    vehicleInfoList.append(VehicleInfo("00045b1b-0ac9-4dce", "2023-07-26T17:27:38Z", "134b785e-e013-41b1-aabc-094a90b95482"))
    vehicleInfoList.append(VehicleInfo("00045b1b-0ac9-4dce", "2023-07-26T18:04:16Z", "51fb0e53-2938-431c-8825-7f461849dfe3"))
    vehicleInfoList.append(VehicleInfo("00045b1b-0ac9-4dce", "2023-07-26T18:32:46Z", "954a4f96-2c51-403b-9fd5-d07a7cdc35dd"))
    vehicleInfoList.append(VehicleInfo("00045b1b-0ac9-4dce", "2023-07-26T18:40:18Z", "811a1336-27f3-4e8c-99cc-22f5debe21a3"))
    vehicleInfoList.append(VehicleInfo("8eba-55a058fb4dd0f", "2023-07-20T10:35:34Z", "1f036bff-cac4-dddd-ddsa-a7646884fe2e"))
    vehicleInfoList.append(VehicleInfo("8eba-55a058fb4dd0f", "2023-07-20T10:65:34Z", "23226bff-cac4-dddd-ddsa-a7646884fe2e"))

    val vehicleInfoDataset = spark.sqlContext.createDataset(vehicleInfoList)

    val myList = vehicleInfoList.toList

    println("")
    for(ele <- myList){

      println(ele)
    }

    // the return value of custom_agg_function could be array of Case Class which can be exploded and then used to create another dataframe.
    val groupedDataset = vehicleInfoDataset.groupBy("vehicleId").agg( custom_agg_function())  

    spark.sparkContext.stop()

  }
}
```